# swiftui animation how to determine the asymmetric transition in real time

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, transition

It's hard to describe my problem in words.

I want to do a selector behave like that.

[image]

But after I change the browse direction, because I already set the in and out transition, even if I change the transition to the new one, the view still uses the old one to disappear. (the first one and the last one)

Is there some way to solve the problem?

[image]

Here is the code

```
 @State var translations:[String] = ["未知"]
    @State var index = 0
    @State var transition:AnyTransition = .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal:.move(edge: .leading)).combined(with: .opacity)
var transTexts:some View{
        HStack{
            if(translations.count > 1){
                Button {
                    if(index > 0){
                        transition = .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal:.move(edge: .trailing)).combined(with: .opacity)
                        disabled.toggle()
                        index -= 1
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName:"arrowtriangle.backward.circle.fill")
                }
                .disabled(index == 0)
                Text(translations[index])
                    .scroll()
                    .font(.body)
                    .id(index)
                    .disabled(disabled)
                    .transition(transition)
            }
            Spacer()
            if(translations.count  > 1){
                Button {
                    if(index < translations.count-1){
                        transition = .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal:.move(edge: .leading)).combined(with: .opacity)
                        disabled.toggle()
                        index += 1
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName:"arrowtriangle.forward.circle.fill")
                }
                .disabled(index == translations.count - 1)
            }
        }
        .animation(.default,value: index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried manually controlling which transition it is, by using a `Toggle`. The transition works correctly if I just toggled the toggle *before* I switched direction. e.g. go right 3 times, toggle, then go left 3 times.

When you do this automatically with buttons, it seems like the time when `index` changes is "too close" to when `transition` changes, and doesn't have the same effect as when I do it manually.

If you just delay the change of `index` by a tiny amount of time, it should work.

```
transition = ...
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) {
    index += 1 // or -= 1
}
```

Interestingly, `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` doesn't work. You have to give it some time.

I'd also suggest using a `Bool` or enum to encode the direction it is going in, rather than an `AnyTransition`.

Working code:

```
@State var translations:[String] = ["Lorem Ipsum", "Foo Bar baz", "Something Else", "AAAAA", "BBBBB"]
@State var index = 0

@State var isForward = true

var body:some View{
    VStack {
        HStack{
            if(translations.count > 1){
                Button {
                    if(index > 0){
                        isForward = false
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) {
                            index -= 1
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName:"arrowtriangle.backward.circle.fill")
                }
                .disabled(index == 0)
            }
            
            if translations.count > 0 {
                Text(translations[index])
                    .font(.body)
                    .id(index)
                    .transition(
                        // I did not combine with .opacity here to make it more obvious
                        isForward ?
                            .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal:.move(edge: .leading)) :
                                .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal:.move(edge: .trailing))
                    )
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            if(translations.count  > 1){
                Button {
                    if index < translations.count - 1 {
                        isForward = true
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) {
                            index += 1
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName:"arrowtriangle.forward.circle.fill")
                }
                .disabled(index == translations.count - 1)
            }
        }
        .animation(.default,value: index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. However, would be great to figure out a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

While @Sweeper solution is correct, I wish to illustrate how it can be modified for ease in many circumstances.

The requirement to set both transition type and then Dispatching index update is not convenient and can easily lead to errors.

And while Dispatching is necessary – you can actually outsource this part to a dedicated object :)

Illustrating for my own code, but the concept is the same

```
enum CustomTransition {
    case next, back
    var value: AnyTransition {
        switch self {
        case .next:
            return AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading))
        case .back:
            return AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing))
        }
    }
}

class StateModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var transition: CustomTransition = .next
    var counter = 0 {
        willSet {
            if newValue > counter {
                transition = CustomTransition.next
            }
            else {
                transition = CustomTransition.back
            }
        }
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.001) {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Playground: View {
    @ObservedObject var stateModel = StateModel()
    var idForStransition: String {
        return "\(stateModel.counter) \(stateModel.transition == .next ? "next" : "prev")"
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Count is \(stateModel.counter)")
                            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
                    }
                    .background(Color.red)
                }
                .id(idForStransition)
                .transition(stateModel.transition.value)
                .animation(.easeIn, value: stateModel.counter)
                HStack {
                    Button("Previous") {
                        stateModel.counter -= 1
                    }
                    Button("Next") {
                        stateModel.counter += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Playground()
}
```

The benefit is that you only need to have transition-deciding logic in one place. Then, just increment the counter.

**Note 1**
I don't know why, but even though you are setting transition in `willSet`, you still need `Dispatch` in `didSet`

**Note 2**
It is important to ensure that `id` which you use is such that it identifies the counter **AND** transition type as well.