# Swiftui dynamic transition on view insertion/removal

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, view

I have a use case with a vertical menu with items: `link_target1`, ..., `link_target5`.
And I have a container that display a `View` associated with one of those items.
When I click on one of the menu items, I set a state and display the matching view according to this state.
What i'm trying to achieve, is a dynamic sliding effect on views transition:
If I go from `target3` to `target1` for example, i'm moving upward. So both views should slide to the bottom.
`target3 view` disappears by sliding down and `target1 view` appears by sliding down also.
So it's like all views are vertically stacked and by clicking to the menu I slide from one to another.
I need to be able to control, at the same time, the transition of the discarded and presented view and I'm only able to do that when the user actually click on the menu (cause otherwise, I don't know if we are going up or down).

The code looks like this:

```swift
enum ViewScreen: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case target1
    case target2
    case target3
    case target4
    case target5
        
    var id: String { return self.rawValue }
    var index: Int { ViewScreen.allCases.firstIndex(of: self) ?? 0 }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var target: ViewScreen = .target1 {
        willSet {
            self.previousTarget = target
        }
    }
    @State var previousTarget: ViewScreen = .target1
    var direction: AnyTransition {
        get {
            previousTarget.index <= target.index ? .move(edge: .top) : .move(edge: .bottom)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            SidebarView(target: $target) // It just set target to the clicked link           
            Group {
                switch target {
                    case .target1: View1()
                    case .target2: View2()
                    case .target3: View3()
                    case .target4: View4()
                    case .target5: View5()
                }
            }.transition(AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: direction))
        }
    }
}
```

Is it even possible with transitions? Any help is welcome. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `willSet` here because it doesn't actually get called. You are passing a binding to the sidebar, and the sidebar sets the binding's `wrappedValue`. `willSet` only gets called when you directly do `target = ...` in `ContentView`.

I would have a `@State` storing the transition to use. Change that state when `target` changes.

```
@State var target: ViewScreen = .target1
@State var direction: AnyTransition = .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .bottom), removal: .move(edge: .top))

...

.onChange(of: target) { oldValue, newValue in
    if oldValue.index > newValue.index {
        direction = .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .top), removal: .move(edge: .bottom))
    } else {
        direction = .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .bottom), removal: .move(edge: .top))
    }
}
```

Notice that the transition is asymmetric. A transition like `.move(edge: .top)` moves the view from top to bottom when the view appears, but moves the view from bottom to top when it disappears. IMO, `.move(towards:)` is a more suitable name than `.move(edge:)`.

Alternatively, you can replace

```
.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .top), removal: .move(edge: .bottom))
```

with `.push(from: .top)`, and the opposite case with `.push(from: .bottom)`. Unlike `.move` which always moves the view towards the same edge, `push` always moves the view in the same direction. `.push` also has opacity built-in, so you don't need to combine it with `.opacity`.

Now we have the situation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76845096/5133585), where the transition would not update correctly when changing directions. The `target` that controls which view to show, needs to be updated just a little later than `direction`.

Here is an minimal example:

```
@State var pickerTarget: ViewScreen = .target1
@State var target: ViewScreen = .target1
@State var direction: AnyTransition = .push(from: .bottom)

var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .top) {
        Picker("Pick", selection: $pickerTarget) {
            ForEach(ViewScreen.allCases, id: \.self) {
                Text($0.rawValue)
            }
        }
        Group {
            switch target {
                case .target1: Text("1")
                case .target2: Text("2")
                case .target3: Text("3")
                case .target4: Text("4")
                case .target5: Text("5")
            }
        }
        .transition(direction)
    }
    .onChange(of: pickerTarget) { oldValue, newValue in
        if oldValue.index > newValue.index {
            direction = .push(from: .top)
        } else {
            direction = .push(from: .bottom)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2)) {
                target = newValue
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sweeper. Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately it does not seems to work. It's quite random. Sometimes the leaving and coming view are crossing each other (one goes down and the other goes up). It's like the animation starts before the new direction is set on the old view.

Comment: @Vincent I cannot reproduce that with the minimal example in my answer. Did you apply this to your real code or did you run the minimal example in my answer? That said, I do remember a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76845096/5133585). If that still doesn't work for you, please show a [mcve].

Comment: the solution on your other post fixed it. By adding a small delay, it works.  So we set the direction and after this short delay, we set the target. Is it a viable solution or could it leads to race condition if the device is slowing down for example?

Comment: @Vincent I don't think there would be race conditions. Everything is on the same dispatch queue.

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper!